# Appropriate Paths for Resources in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, gradle

in my AndroidManifest.xml, I have

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/iC_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

And when I run gradle build, I keep getting the errors

```
resource drawable/ic_launcher (aka com.example.MyProject:drawable/ic_launcher) not found
resource string/app_name (aka com.example.MyProject:string/app_name) not found
resource style/AppTheme (aka com.example.MyProject:style/AppTheme) not found
```

I'm guessing that the @drawable @string and @style correspond to the directories with the same names I've seen before when I used Android Studio. But now that I don't use Android Studio anymore, where should I put them?
Currently my Java files are located in

> app/src/main/java/MyProject

and my AndroidManifest.xml file is located in

> app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

The directories are generated via gradle init; do I need to rearrange them?

Comment: what are you using now instead of android studio?

Comment: vim with gradle build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing that the @drawable @string and @style correspond to the directories with the same names I've seen before when I used Android Studio

There is no `style` directory and there is no `string` directory. Style and string resources go in a `values` directory.

> But now that I don't use Android Studio anymore, where should I put them?

The same place that Android Studio puts them, and the same place that they are in any Android project. For a module named `app` and a source set named `main`, you would create subdirectories under `app/src/main/res` for different [resource types and resource sets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).

FWIW, [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) explains all of this.

Comment: There's a app/src/main/resouces directory... is that the same as app/src/main/res?

Comment: I created the directory app/src/main/res and a drawable dir beneath it. Then I put a file ic_launcher_example.png in it, and changed the ic_launcher in the AndroidManifest.xml accordingly. However gradle build still says it's not found. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @FelinaSaber: "is that the same as app/src/main/res?" -- no. Android does not normally use a `resources` directory. "Am I doing something wrong?" -- I have no idea. I encourage you to learn Android from structured educational resources (books, online courses, etc.). While they will focus on Android Studio, the programming approaches, such as directory structures, remain the same.